# How to show a loading bar when reading an NFC Tag from a device in compose

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

I do not know how to display a loading bar, or any other composable function to the user when an app has received a new intent and is reading the devices tag.

I have tried to move the intent handler into a composable using DisposableEffect but I cannot execute any composable code inside the Consumer nor inside of the onNewIntent.